# При чтение pdf файла в php выводит кракозябры

Tags: php, парсер, pdf

Есть pdf файл, есть библиотека для чтения smalot/pdfparser.

Суть в том что при чтение pdf файла выводятся непонятные кракозябры, пробовал менять кодировку не помогает.

Я думаю что ошибка уже в самой библиотеке, и какие вообще есть библиотеки для чтения pdf файлов ?

Ссылка на библиотеку: https://github.com/smalot/pdfparser

Ссылку на pdf дать не могу т.к. в нем есть паспортные данные.

Вот сам код:

```
<?php
//Подключение автозагрузчика composer'a
include 'vendor/autoload.php';

$parser = new \Smalot\PdfParser\Parser();
$pdfDoc = $parser->parseFile('doc.pdf');
$pagesPdf = $pdfDoc->getPages();
foreach ($pagesPdf as $page)
{
    echo$page->getText();
}
?>
```

Вот скрин что мне выдает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Существует несколько возможных проблемы.

- Документ в формате PDF использует шрифт, который не является стандартным. И шрифт не включен в документ в результате, шрифт по умолчанию используется, который не содержит правильные глифы. Это может быть исправлено путем встраивания шрифта. Или по тому, у вас есть шрифт в системе, что используется в исходном документе.
- Документ в формате PDF не содержит карте \toUnicode. Это сопоставление гарантирует, что символы могут быть прочитаны и скопированы. Это не может быть исправлено.
- Документ в формате PDF содержит неисправный \ActualText карте. ActualText может использоваться для набора текста на символы. Например, в Германии, некоторые слова написаны по-разному, если они пишутся через дефис. Для того, чтобы обеспечить правильное слово, когда вы копируете, используемые ActualText это.

Если вы создаете документ, попробуйте использовать iText. Это отличный набор инструментов для создания и изменения документов PDF.